# Simplifying angular.json configurations for internationalization

Tags: angular

I have recently started to look at [i18n](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)* under Angular and found that it seems to require me to write configurations for *each* locale.

Here is just *two* of them:

```js
"en": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ],
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "budgets": [
    {
      "type": "initial",
      "maximumWarning": "2mb",
      "maximumError": "5mb"
    },
    {
      "type": "anyComponentStyle",
      "maximumWarning": "6kb",
      "maximumError": "10kb"
    }
  ],
  "outputPath": "dist/web/en",
  "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
  "i18nFormat": "xlf",
  "i18nLocale": "en"
},
"de": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ],
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "budgets": [
    {
      "type": "initial",
      "maximumWarning": "2mb",
      "maximumError": "5mb"
    },
    {
      "type": "anyComponentStyle",
      "maximumWarning": "6kb",
      "maximumError": "10kb"
    }
  ],
  "outputPath": "dist/web/de",
  "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.de.xlf",
  "i18nFormat": "xlf",
  "i18nLocale": "de"
},
```

Imo this is ugly, error prone and violates what we should avoid the most: code duplication.

So, I was wondering, can we somehow simplify this?

Comment: That's how the docs tell you to do it: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-aot-compiler. If there were alternatives that's where I'd expect them to be be. Given that every other configuration option is the same, I'd pass the locale from the command line: `ng build --prod --outputPath=dist/web/de --i18n-locale=de ...` and wrap that in a trivial shell script to be able to do e.g. `./prod-build.sh de`.

Comment: It's coming. See https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/12/10/angular-localize/

Comment: @JBNizet Very nice. Thanks for that link!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Alright. I guess for now this will do until Angular 9. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you can significantly improve it with Angular 9 by adding this part to project:

```
"i18n": {
  "sourceLocale": "en",
  "locales": {
    "fr": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf"
    "de": "src/locale/messages.de.xlf"
  }
}
```

And then keep one production config like this:

```
"production-iofrog": {
  "budgets": [{
    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
    "maximumWarning": "6kb"
  }],
  "fileReplacements": [{
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }],
  "localize": [
     "fr",
     "de"
  ],
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "outputPath": "dist/iofrog",
  "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
  "deleteOutputPath": false
},
```

Then you can do

```
ng build --configuration production --localize
```

It will build an app using your production config and then apply the translations, so it will be much, much faster than with i18m in Angular 8.

The only issue I have found in my project is that you cannot use this --localize approach if you need file replacement for every locale, because it is not supported yet: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17126